# Is there any notification message for SwitchDesktop Windows API?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

There is one api called **SwitchDesktop** to change active input desktop in windows. Now I want to receive notification when other process calls **SwitchDesktop** api to change desktop. Is there any notification available for this ?

SwitchDesktop Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686347(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Those MSDN pages don't mention anything about this, might be a job for Spy++.

Comment: Use [`SetWinEventHook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and listen for the [`EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event.